# duda procedimiento salida por pantalla datos de una lista c++

Tags: c++, lista

Buenas, tengo un ejercicio en el que estoy atascado, este es el enunciado:

> Impleméntese  el  método  RECURSIVO(NO CONFUNDIR POR FAVOR CON OTRO EJERCICIO QUE PUSE DONDE DICE NO RECURSIVO, ESTE SÍ ES RECURSIVO) de  la  clase   `dll_t  ostream&    dll_t<T>::write_reverse(dll_node_t<T>*  n,  ostream&    os) const`  que muestra en  orden   inverso el  contenido   de  la  lista   enlazada    invocante   a   partir  del nodo    n.  Sólo     se podrá   utilizar    el  método  `dll_node_t*    get_next()` de  la  clase   `dll_node_t`    para    acceder al  elemento    siguiente.  En  ningún   caso   se  permitirá   utilizar    el  método  `dll_node_t*    get_prev()`.

ESTA SON LAS CLASES QUE ME DAN:

```
template <class T>
class dll_t {
private:
 dll_node_t<T>* head_;
 dll_node_t<T>* tail_;
 int sz_;
public:
 dll_t(void);
 ~dll_t(void);
void insert_tail(dll_node_t<T>*);
 void insert_head(dll_node_t<T>*);
 dll_node_t<T>* extract_tail(void);
 dll_node_t<T>* extract_head(void);
 dll_node_t<T>* get_tail(void) const;
 dll_node_t<T>* get_head(void) const;
 bool empty(void);
 void remove(dll_node_t<T>*);
 ostream& write(ostream& os) const;
 void select(dll_t<dll_node_t<T>*>& L, const T& x);
private:
bool igual(const T& a, const T&b);
};

template <class T>
class dll_node_t {
private:
 dll_node_t<T>* next_;
 dll_node_t<T>* prev_;
T data_;
public:
 dll_node_t();
dll_node_t(const T& data);
 virtual ~dll_node_t(void);
void set_next(dll_node_t<T>*);
void set_prev(dll_node_t<T>*);
dll_node_t<T>* get_next(void) const;
dll_node_t<T>* get_prev(void) const;
void set_data(const T& data);
T get_data(void) const;
ostream& write(ostream& os) const;
};
```

yo lo intenté así, sé que está mal mi planteamiento, que tengo lagunas en 
   algunos aspectos, pero agradezco cualquier ayuda:

```
template<class T>

   ostream& dll_t<T>:: write_reverse(dll_node_t<T>* n, ostream& os) const {
     assert(!empty());
     while(n!=NULL){
       n=n->get_data();
       n.write(os);
   }
```

me quedé ahí, se agradece cualquier ayuda.

Gracias.

Comment: Tu código es muy (muy) confuso, no sólo por estar usando una indentación que personalmente me parece confusa, si no principalmente porque no aportas un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) de tu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problema.

Parece que tienes problemas para entender la recursión o no te la han explicado al detalle. Permíteme citar un extracto de [la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n_(ciencias_de_computaci%C3%B3n)) (el resaltado es mío):

> La mayoría de los lenguajes de programación dan soporte a la recursión **permitiendo a una función llamarse a sí misma** desde el texto del programa.

Es decir, para que una llamada sea recursiva, la función recursiva debe llamarse a si misma, y tú no lo estás haciendo<sup>1</sup>:

```
write_reverse(dll_node_t<T>* n, ostream& os) const {
    assert(!empty());
    while(n!=NULL){
        n=n->get_data();
        n.write(os);
    }
} // DONDE esta la llamada a write_reverse dentro de write_reverse?!
```

#### Propuesta.

Para imprimir cualquier secuencia en orden inverso usando recursión, debes ir saltando hasta el último nodo y, una vez en éste, imprimir y desenroscar la recursión.

```
write_reverse(dll_node_t<T>* n, ostream& os) const {
    if (n) { // Si el nodo no es null.
        write_reverse(n->next_, os); // Avanzamos.
        n.write(os); // Imprimimos.
    }
}
```

En esta posible aproximación al problema, dado que primero se avanza y luego se imprime, se mostraría la lista en sentido inverso; dado que se llama a si misma sería recursiva. Ojo, asume que el puntero `next_` es nulo cuando no hay elemento siguiente.

#### Consejo.

Repasa los conceptos básicos de C++, parece que no los tienes suficientemente claros y esto hará que te sea difícil abordar dudas como esta (o más complejas) sin ayuda.

---

<sup>1</sup>Además de que tu función es incorrecta ya que le falta la llave de cierre, la marca de plantilla pertenece a su clase no a la función miembro y la llamada a `n=n->get_data()` carece de sentido (y ni siquiera debería compilar).